# Getting an error uninstalling the old NS 6.5

Tags: npm, nativescript

I did

`sudo npm uninstall -g nativescript`

and got the following error

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> nativescript@6.5.1 preuninstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node preuninstall.js

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mini/.npmrc'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341:35)
    at maybeReadIni (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/libnpmconfig/index.js:81:14)
    at Object.getNpmConfig [as read] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/libnpmconfig/index.js:43:32)
    at NpmConfigService.readConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/npm-config-service.js:13:32)
    at new NpmConfigService (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/npm-config-service.js:7:14)
    at Yok.resolveConstructor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:293:20)
    at Yok.resolveByName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:321:33)
    at Yok.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:258:25)
    at ctor.$inject.args.map.paramName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:288:29)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Yok.resolveConstructor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:283:48)
    at Yok.resolveByName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:321:33)
    at Yok.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:258:25)
    at ctor.$inject.args.map.paramName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/yok.js:288:29)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
Error while reporting exception: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mini/.local/share/.nativescript-cli/a05e966313d1a8e32b13c35910ae824e'
```

I ignored the error and tried to install the new one and stuck on same error.

Now I can't even revert back to 6.5

Help!

Comment: It must be something to do with permissions with your NPM. Doesn't seem anything to do with {N} specifically. Also it's not recommended to use NPM as sudo.

Comment: I can't do a clean uninstall now - with our without sudo. I'd like to do an uninstall and then a new install without sudo.